# Pass Additional Information to Alternative Performance Metric in R and caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I would like to use a custom performance metric to train models using `caret.` Using the clear documentation [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html), I am able to create a new performance metric. However, I would like to pass in additional information for each prediction to the `performance.metric` function below. I see that `data` has columns for `pred` and `obs`, which are the predicted and observed data, respectively. I also see that is possible to add `weights` and `classProbs` as the documentation clearly specifies. Is it possible to pass in additional information for each prediction?

Specifically, I want to evaluate the performance of an asset prediction algorithm using the dollar return from the sequence of predictions produced by the model. My predictions (data$pred) are the asset's daily change. To get a dollarReturn for each day, I need to pass in the asset's daily change. I can't figure out how to pass in information for the `assetChange` object.

Here is the performance metric:

```
performance.metric = function(data, lev= NULL, model = NULL,
                              investment = 20000){

  if (!all(levels(data[, "pred"]) == levels(data[, "obs"]))) 
    stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")

  #custom performance metric
  assetChange = #this should be a vector of length nrows(data)
    #with the percentage change for the asset each day

  percReturn = ifelse(data[,"obs"] == data[, "pred"], abs(assetChange), -abs(assetChange) )
  #the strategy involves buying when predicting to increase and selling when predicted to decrease
  #so when the prediction is right, it gets the abs of the percent change and else loses that amount

  dollarReturn = rep(0, nrow(data))
  dollarReturn[1] = investment*percReturn[1]
  for (i in 2:length(dollarReturn)){
    dollarReturn[i] = dollarReturn[i-1]*percReturn[i]
  }

  out <- c(dollarReturn)
  names(out) <- c("dollarReturn")
  out
}
```

I could imagine a (hackish) way of passing in the information through the `weights` column in `data`, but more generally, is it possible to add columns to the `data` object from outside `performance.metric` so that this function has the necessary data?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't see an easy way of doing this. I'd like to avoid refactoring the functions to pass in ancillary information since that might break backwards compatibility.

However, I've added [an issue to github](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/134) that might help. The data exposed to the function for calculating performance exposes columns for the observed outcome, the predicted value, and class probabilities. I'll also pass in the row index so that the holdout values can be tied back to the original data and let lexical scoping do the rest.

It would help if you created a synthetic example and add it to the issue so that we can test the solution.

Max

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, row indexes should be sufficient for this class of performance metrics. I'll work on a synthetic example, and add to the issue on github when time allows.